# Listview infinita no android

Tags: java, android, banco-de-dados, listview, lazy-loading

Tenho um app que consome um web service, só que eu tenho uma chamada genérica que busca todos os usuários e esta demorando muito porque tenho diversos registros, eu quero fazer assim o usuário vai descendo a tela e vai aparecendo mais dados no listview, só que minha chamada no web service é assim `SELECT * FROM ALUNOS`, e eu gostaria de fazer um limit, minha pergunta é: vou ter que fazer vários limits ou só implementando o `OnScrollListener` ele já da certo?

Estou perdido não sei como implementar isso.

Meu método de buscarTodos do AlunoDAO do WEB SERVICE

```
public ArrayList<Aluno> buscarTodosUsuarios() {

    ArrayList<Aluno> lista = new ArrayList<Aluno>();

    try {

        Connection conn = ConectaMySql.obtemConexao();

        String queryInserir = "SELECT * FROM ALUNO ORDER BY NOME";

        PreparedStatement ppStm = conn.prepareStatement(queryInserir);

        ResultSet rSet = ppStm.executeQuery();

        while (rSet.next()) {

            Aluno user = new Aluno();

            user.setId(rSet.getInt(1));

            user.setNome(rSet.getString(2));

            user.setLogin(rSet.getString(3));

            user.setPass(rSet.getString(4));

            user.setCurso(rSet.getString(5));

            user.setSegunda(rSet.getString(6));

            user.setM1(rSet.getString(7));

            user.setTerca(rSet.getString(8));

            user.setM2(rSet.getString(9));

            user.setQuarta(rSet.getString(10));

            user.setM3(rSet.getString(11));

            user.setQuinta(rSet.getString(12));

            user.setM4(rSet.getString(13));

            user.setSexta(rSet.getString(14));

            user.setM5(rSet.getString(15));

            user.setFoto(rSet.getBytes(16));

            lista.add(user);

        }

        conn.close();

    } catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        return null;

    }

    return lista;

}
```

Meu método do AlunoDAO da minha aplicação

```
public List<Aluno> buscarTodosUsuarios() {

    List<Aluno> listaUsr = new ArrayList<Aluno>();

    SoapObject buscarUsuarios = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, BUSCAR_TODOS);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(buscarUsuarios);

    envelope.implicitTypes = true;

    HttpTransportSE http = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try {
        http.call("urn:" + BUSCAR_TODOS, envelope);

        if (envelope.getResponse() instanceof SoapObject) {
            SoapObject resposta = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

            Aluno usr = new Aluno();

            usr.setId(Integer.parseInt(resposta.getProperty("id")
                    .toString()));
            usr.setNome(resposta.getProperty("nome").toString());
            usr.setCurso(resposta.getProperty("curso").toString());
            usr.setSegunda(resposta.getProperty("segunda").toString());
            usr.setM1(resposta.getProperty("m1").toString());
            usr.setTerca(resposta.getProperty("terca").toString());
            usr.setM2(resposta.getProperty("m2").toString());
            usr.setQuarta(resposta.getProperty("quarta").toString());
            usr.setM3(resposta.getProperty("m3").toString());
            usr.setQuinta(resposta.getProperty("quinta").toString());
            usr.setM4(resposta.getProperty("m4").toString());
            usr.setSexta(resposta.getProperty("sexta").toString());
            usr.setM5(resposta.getProperty("m5").toString());
            String foto = resposta.getProperty("foto").toString();

            usr.setTesteFoto(foto.toString());

            byte[] bt = Base64.decode(foto, Base64.DEFAULT);
            usr.setFoto(bt);
            listaUsr.add(usr);
        } else {
            Vector<SoapObject> retorno = (Vector<SoapObject>) envelope
                    .getResponse();

            for (SoapObject resposta : retorno) {

                Aluno usr = new Aluno();

                usr.setId(Integer.parseInt(resposta.getProperty("id")
                        .toString()));
                usr.setNome(resposta.getProperty("nome").toString());
                usr.setCurso(resposta.getProperty("curso").toString());
                usr.setSegunda(resposta.getProperty("segunda").toString());
                usr.setM1(resposta.getProperty("m1").toString());
                usr.setTerca(resposta.getProperty("terca").toString());
                usr.setM2(resposta.getProperty("m2").toString());
                usr.setQuarta(resposta.getProperty("quarta").toString());
                usr.setM3(resposta.getProperty("m3").toString());
                usr.setQuinta(resposta.getProperty("quinta").toString());
                usr.setM4(resposta.getProperty("m4").toString());
                usr.setSexta(resposta.getProperty("sexta").toString());
                usr.setM5(resposta.getProperty("m5").toString());
                String foto = resposta.getProperty("foto").toString();

                usr.setTesteFoto(foto.toString());

                byte[] bt = Base64.decode(foto, Base64.DEFAULT);
                usr.setFoto(bt);
                listaUsr.add(usr);
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

    return listaUsr;
}
```

A classe que pega meu listview

```
public class ListarTodosActivity extends Activity {

private ListView lvUsuario;
private List<Aluno> usrs;
private AlunoDAO dao;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_listartodos);

    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
            .permitAll().build();
    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);

    dao = new AlunoDAO();
    lvUsuario = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvListarTodos);

    usrs = dao.buscarTodosUsuarios();

    AlunoAdapter usrAdp = new AlunoAdapter(this, usrs);
    lvUsuario.setAdapter(usrAdp);

    lvUsuario.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {

            Aluno aluno = (Aluno) lvUsuario.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Intent intent = new Intent(ListarTodosActivity.this,
                    DetalhesActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ALUNO_NOME", aluno.getNome().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ALUNO_CURSO", aluno.getCurso().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ALUNO_FOTO", aluno.getTesteFoto().toString());// envio
                                                                            // a
                                                                            // string
                                                                            // da
                                                                            // foto
                                                                            // do
                                                                            // banco
                                                                            // para
                                                                            // meu
                                                                            // detalhesActivity.class
            intent.putExtra("ALUNO_DIA1", aluno.getSegunda().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ALUNO_M1", aluno.getM1().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ALUNO_DIA2", aluno.getTerca().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ALUNO_M2", aluno.getM2().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ALUNO_DIA3", aluno.getQuarta().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ALUNO_M3", aluno.getM3().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ALUNO_DIA4", aluno.getQuinta().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ALUNO_M4", aluno.getM4().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ALUNO_DIA5", aluno.getSexta().toString());
            intent.putExtra("ALUNO_M5", aluno.getM5().toString());

            startActivity(intent);

        }

    });
}
```

Minha classe Adapter do meu listview

```
public class AlunoAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private List<Aluno> usrs;
private Context context;

public AlunoAdapter(Context context, List<Aluno> usrs) {
    this.usrs = usrs;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return usrs.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int arg0) {
    return usrs.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int arg0) {
    return usrs.get(arg0).getId();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(
            R.layout.activity_modelo_aluno, parent, false);

    ImageView imgFoto = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imgFoto);
    TextView txtNome = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtNome);
    TextView txtCurso = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txtCurso);

    Aluno usuarioDaVez = usrs.get(position);

    txtNome.setText(usuarioDaVez.getNome());
    txtCurso.setText(usuarioDaVez.getCurso());

     Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(usuarioDaVez.getFoto(),
     0, usuarioDaVez.getFoto().length);
     imgFoto.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    return rootView;
}}
```

Answer (score 3):

O principal problema é que você está fazendo uma consulta e retornando uma lista de Alunos. O ideal seria você usar um `CursorLoader` e um `CursorAdapter`. As principais vantagem de se usar `CursorLoader` são:

1. O carregamento dos dados é feito em background (fora da UIThread), portanto, a tela não trava durante o carregamento dos dados.
2. O carregamento de dados é feito sob demanda, ou seja, se sua tela só consegue mostrar 10 itens, só 10 itens serão carregados em memória e conforme vc vai deslizando a lista os outros itens vao sendo carregados em memória.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisará adaptar os SQL's do seu web service para trabalhar com `LIMIT`e `OFFSET`. Dessa forma você conseguirá listar os usuários dentro de um range [0-10].

Já no aplicativo, existem várias bibliotecas que fazem esse gerenciamento para efetuar a requisição e atualizar o `ListView` ou `RecyclerView`. Caso você não encontre, você consegue saber se a última `View` de sua lista está sendo exibida através do método `mListView.getLastVisiblePosition()`.

Espero que ajude!